# Can't execute function from load.json

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons, minecraft-behavior-packs

I am trying to create a Minecraft Bedrock edition behavior pack that places a structure at a set of coordinates on load.  The file is shops.mcaddon.  Inside is a folder called shopsBP.  Inside shopsBP is a functions folder, structures folder, manifest.json, and pack_icon.png.

I am trying to execute the function shops.mcfunction from the functions folder via the load.json file.  I have entered this into load.json:

```
{
 "values": [ "shops" ]
}
```

Nothing happens with this.  But if I put the same thing in tick.json it works, but I don't want it to run every tick, just once on load.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of looking around, and unfortunately, I do not believe that BE supports the `load.json` tag.

I did find [this article](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/commands/on-first-world-load.html) from bedrock.dev, which shows how to run a command the first time the world loads using a scoreboard value and `tick.json`.